# How can I see all of the links I've ever posted from the new Jan. 2011 Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook, sharing

There used to be a box on the lower left-hand side of my facebook profile where I could see the links I'd most recently posted, and then click to see all the links I had ever posted previously. That box seems nonexistant in the layout redesign that went into effect in January, 2011. With this new layout, where can I see all my links? I'm looking for something I shared some time ago, and can't find it!

Comment: Check out http://trunk.ly @Nhinkle, though I'm not sure this is what you want, so leaving as a comment

Comment: You can do it with this app: https://apps.facebook.com/findmylinks/

Comment: I used the app for more than one year , but now , is showing only the las links I posted....how can i Correct that?

Comment: well it says find *my* links, so it does find *your* links, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why they removed it but,

It is under the following format

`http://www.facebook.com/posted.php?id=[YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID]`

and your friends' recent links are http://www.facebook.com/posted.php

**The above does not work anymore - Tuesday 15th November 2011**

Here is a chart done by this [page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/How-to-Find-Your-Missing-Links/193512657394331) that shows recent applications that show links

[image: Facebook Links Chart]

Comment: It doesn't give the "My Links" anymore :(

Comment: @WilburLikeSmith I am actually stumped why they removed it...